# Return BOOL after UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I am using jailbroken iPhone on iOS 6

I am trying to return BOOL value only after pressing an UIAlertView

```
%hook foo 
-(void)foo
{
   NSLog (@"foo");             
   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"alertview"
                 message:@"alert"
                 delegate:self
                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                 otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

   [alertView show];
   [alertView release];   

   if ( button OK )  //  only if button OK 
      %orig;
   }
   %new(v@:@@)
   +(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
  if ((buttonIndex == 1) {
         return true;
  }
}
%end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step by step for using AlertView Delegates (correctly):

Be sure to delegate to self, and have UIAlertViewDelegate set in your .h header file.

then initialize your Alert View like this from your action or viewDidLoad or wherever:

```
 [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"Select yes or no" delegate:self  cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil] show];
```

handle your alerts from the self delegation like this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
      //this would be the yes button or cancel
      if (buttonIndex == 0){
        //set variable to false or user press cancel
       }
      if (buttonIndex == 1){
        //set variable to true or user press OK
       }
      // buttonIndex would by 1,2,3,4 depending on the number of otherButtons you have. Of course I'd suggest putting this into a case statement, instead of a mess of if thens. 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not how user input works in iOS.  When you call `[alertView show]`, all it does is signal to UIKit that when it next updates the screen, the alert view should be visible.  It doesn't display the alert view itself, nor does it wait for the user to press something.  It sets a flag, then it returns instantly.  The alert view is only shown after your code returns and UIKit updates the screen.

Your `if ( button OK )` statement runs *before* the alert view is shown.  It's not possible to put code at that point to react to the user input.  The correct place to put it is in the delegate method `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`.

Comment: Jim is 100% correct. You have to use the UIAlertViewDelegate method, and override it, and intercept the buttonIndex. If you have multiple Alerts you have to set a tag number for the AlertView, and create cases for the different tags numbers, then within each different tag, different buttonIndexes.